# one interesting phenomenon about swift Closure

Tags: swift

I have a class object in the controller, and then I have a closure in this object.
I assign a function of the controller to the object's closure, and then the page does not deinit.

How can I solve this problem?

```
import UIKit

class SecondViewController: UIViewController {
    let test = TestObject()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        self.test.select = self.selectButton(index:)
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.test.doSomethine()
    }

    func selectButton(index:Int){
        print(index)
    }

    deinit {
        print("deinit")
    }
}
```

---

```
import UIKit

typealias selectBtnBlock = (_ index:Int)->()

class TestObject: NSObject {
    var select:selectBtnBlock?

    func doSomethine(){
        self.select!(1)
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is because your `test` object's select closure **strongly** captures your `SecondViewController` when you do the following:

```
self.test.select = self.selectButton(index:)
```

I recommend you do some reading about weak and strong types via Apple's Swift language reference. The "interesting phenomenon" you encountered is called a strong reference cycle.

Essentially, since Swift uses ARC as its memory management model, any object that is referenced by at least one other object else will be kept alive, and its memory not deallocated.

In your case, `test` has captured its parent `SecondViewContoller` via the line I mentioned. What that means is you have a situation like the following:

```
SecondViewController -> (owns) test // since its a member of the class
test -> (strongly captures) SecondViewController // via the assignment
```

This causes a strong reference cycle between the two, and does not allow ARC to deallocate either.

When it (ARC) tries to free up `test`, is knows that `SecondViewController` references it, so it can be freed only if the parent is also freed. When it tries to deallocate `SecondViewController`, ARC knows that this object is referenced by `test.select` closure.

Since both have a reference count greater than one, neither will get deallocated.

One way to solve your issue is to write:

```
self.test.select = { 
    [weak self] // weakly capture self, this prevents a ref cycle 
    (i:Int)->() in // a closure that accepts an Int
    guard let s = self else { return } // check if self is not nil
    s.selectButton(index: i) // finally invoke the required method
}
```

Another way, similar intent:

```
self.test.select = { [weak self] i in
    self?.selectButton(index: i)
}
```

The `weak` keyword in this context is used to tell the Swift compiler that I do not want to keep a strong reference to what I am capturing (`self` in this case).